# Main Thread Runloop gets blocked on opening nsmenu

Tags: cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, nsmenu, nsrunloop, nsstatusitem

I have an application for which the UI element includes an `NSStatusItem` and a menu. Inside my application , I am using `NSTask` asynchronously to perform some operation and I am using the output obtained using the  `NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification` to update the menu. But now whenever I click and open the menu , the main runloop goes into  `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode` and the notification posting fails. So basically with my menu open , no operation takes place on the main thread. Now I found a similar problem on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808016/how-does-apple-update-the-airport-menu-while-it-is-open-how-to-change-nsmenu-w) post but the accepted solution there does not seem to help. I understand that for `NSNotificationCenter` , the `NSRunloopDefaultMode` must not be blocked. Is there anyway to alter this bahaviour??? Can anyone please help ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I'm guessing is that you have an `NSFileHandle` that represents the `NSTask`'s `stdout`,  and you've asked it to [`-readInBackgroundAndNotify`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000304-readInBackgroundAndNotify).

The problem with this, as you've found, is that this only notifies when the runloop is in the default mode.  If the runloop enters another mode (such as when a menu is open), then your notifications will queue up on the main runloop and will wait until the runloop re-enters the default mode.

What you want to use instead is the [`-readInBackgroundAndNotifyForModes:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000304-readInBackgroundAndNotifyForModes_) method, to which you would pass an array containing both `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` and `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode`.  This would indicate to the runloop that you want to be notified of any available data when the runloop is either in the default mode or the event tracking mode.