# libPusher + updating an open NSMenu

Tags: objective-c, pusher

I have an `NSMenu` that I want to update with items pushed to my app through [pusherapp](http://pusher.com/) and received using the [libPusher client library](https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher). But events seem not to be received in `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode`.

Given the following snippet:

```
[channel bindToEventNamed:@"my_event" handleWithBlock:^(PTPusherEvent *event) {
    NSLog(@"event received");
}];
```

And I wait for a push to occur while I maintain the menu open, I expect to receive the event immediately but I only receive it when I close the menu.

I also tried passing the main queue to `bindToEventNamed:handleWithBlock:queue:` (using `dispatch_get_main_queue();`), to no avail.

So I'm left wondering whether I'm doing something wrong or there's a bug in libPusher?

Comment: take a look at, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808016/how-does-apple-update-the-airport-menu-while-it-is-open-how-to-change-nsmenu-w

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm saying by "events seem not to be received in `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode`"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of libPusher. The reason you are seeing this problem is because the underlying WebSocket library used by libPusher, [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/socketrocket) only works in the default run loop mode.

The good news is that this has been fixed in the latest HEAD of SocketRocket. I have tested libPusher agains the latest SocketRocket and can confirm that it fixes this issue and I intend to roll these changes in to the next release.

Now, I've just checked the outstanding Github issue and realised that you were the original reporter of this bug, so you probably know all this already but I'm going to post this answer anyway for posterity.

- [libPusher issue](https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher/issues/62)
- [SocketRocket issue](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket/issues/44)

Comment: Actually, I did post the bug report at github ;)