# KVO : NSMenuItem won't update

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing, nsmenuitem

I'm creating a menuitem as following:

```
NSMenuItem* item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] init];
[item setTitle:device.name];
[item setImage:device.icon];
```

The Device `name` is update for some reason. One of my custom view is updated when the name is updated (Binding/KVO) but the item isn't.

Any idea why ?

Edit : The name was updated like this :

```
[self setValue:[[NSFileManager defaultManager] displayNameAtPath:_path] forKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: How was the `name` updated ?

Comment: Is probably a dublicate of this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808016/how-does-apple-update-the-airport-menu-while-it-is-open-how-to-change-nsmenu-w

Comment: Nope. I talking about a closed menu.